# I want from this program to give me the answer of a+(a+1)+(a+2)...+b

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

> I want from this program to give me the answer of a+(a+1)+(a+2)...+b but it
>   gives me a + b! HELP!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a, b, c;

    cout << "Enter the value of the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a; cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the value of the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b; cout << endl;

    for(a; c <= b; c++){

    c = c + 1;

    }

    cout << "The sum of the numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " is " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` is never initialized

Comment: Keep in mind that the parens are not necessary to resolve any ordering here.  You could turn this into `a * ? + *sum formula* + b`.  No loop should be necessary.  I forget what the sum formula is, and I don't know what your terminator is, but there you go.

Comment: Actually, I see what you're doing now and all you need is the summation formula.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: `(a + b) * (b - a + 1) / 2`, see [Arithmetic_progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: Hint: turn on warning, so compiler may help you with that sort of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you want is here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a, b, c=0;

    cout << "Enter the value of the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a; cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the value of the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b; cout << endl;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)  c+=i;//notice here !!!

    cout << "The sum of the numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " is " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner and I make some mistakes!

Comment: that's not important ! you'll be a professional if you love writing code !